# oracle substr from character until character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string with multiple `/` characters. I need to trim the string before/after each of that character. Example string "231/19/2812-27/1". Each trim will be its own column.

```
Row1 | Row2 | Row3 | Row4 | Row5
231  | 19   | 2812 | 27   |  1
```

Please no regex.
Thank you.

Edit: Edited how the string should be trimmed and represented as a table (27/1)

Comment: Row or field? Cause in your example each string represents a field, not a row.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov, _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh, well, technically you're right. But commonly these words are used interchangeably. For example, here is Microsoft Access "Create a table and add fields" docs: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-table-and-add-fields-8fdc65f9-8d40-4ff5-9212-80e6545e8d87

Comment: yes, columns. sorry for my mistake. you can edit and get some points ;)

Comment: Why `2812-27/1` gives `2812 27/1` and not `2812-27 1`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov, those Excel users... According to the ANSI SQL specification a _field_ is a part of date/time value, e.g. hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select SUBSTR('231/19/2812-27/1',1,instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1)-1) col1,
SUBSTR('231/19/2812-27/1',instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1)+1,(instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1,2)-instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1))-1) col2 ,
SUBSTR('231/19/2812-27/1',instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1,2)+1,(instr('231/19/2812-27/1','-',1,1)-instr('231/19/2812-27/1','/',1,2))-1) col3 ,
SUBSTR('231/19/2812-27/1',(instr('231/19/2812-27/1','-',1,1)+1)) col4
from dual;
```

Comment: can you please explain it a bit, so I can use it for other scenarios, longer strings with more / exmaple "410/18/32/2-47/1". Can't figure it out!

Comment: I am voting this as answer because it is a bit faster than using REGEX_SUBSTR

Comment: subtr, instr is much  faster and useful when we have a more uniform pattern of string. if you need more detailed information on how the above logic works, you can ask me

Comment: Thank you. I will ask you if I stumble in any problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest representing the result in rows, not columns, because in the latter case you have to know the number of columns to construct a query or use dynamic SQL which is quite more complicated and absolutely redundant in your case.

Try this:

```
 with t as (select '231/19/2812-27/1' as str from dual)
 select regexp_substr(str,'[^/]+',1,level) as val
 from t
 connect by regexp_substr(str,'[^/]+',1,level) is not null
```

Yes, it's a regexp and, in my opinion, the easiest way to achieve the result you want. If you do not want to use this then write your own function to split a string.

But, if you still want to represent your result in columns, try this:

```
--edit  removed a , at the end
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, '[^/]+', 1, 1) col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, '[^/]+', 1, 2) col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, '[^/]+', 1, 3) col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, '[^/]+', 1, 4) col4
FROM (select '231/19/2812-27/1' as value from dual) t;
```